# Why does modal not works when calling a remote partial in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

Basic setup works:

translations/_edit_single_translation.html.erb

```
<div id="modalContent" class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

layouts/application.html.erb contains:

```
<%= render 'translations/edit_single_translation' %>

<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade modal-backdrop" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div id="modalDialog" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    Content comes here
  </div>
</div>
```

link:

```
link_to "Translate Link", translations_edit_path(:locale => locale,: key => key), local: true)
```

so this works

from the applications.html.erb I remove:

`<%= render 'translations/edit_single_translation' %>`

and change link to:

`link_to "Translate Link", translations_edit_path(:locale => locale,: key => key), remote: true)`

In javascript/packs/modal-action.js i put:

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render partial: 'translations/edit_single_translation') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal('show');
```

Now it does not work.

when add:

`alert(\'<%= j (render partial: "translations/edit_single_translation") %>')`

to modal-action. I get an alert with `<%= j (render partial: "translations/edit_single_translation") %>`

what am I missing?

[EDITED]

I found out that the 'show' method was called. googling for a day or two i found out that instead of:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
end
```

I had to put:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => false }
    format.html
end
```

in the 'show' method of translations.

then I had to move

```
$("#modalDialog").html('<%= j (render partial: 'edit', locals: { items: @translation } ) %>');
$('#modal-window').modal();
```

from `javascript/packs/modal-action.js` to `translations\show.js.erb`

to make add and update work I placed all translations in a span with the key as id.
to update the corresponding translations after add or edit and close the modal i put:

```
$('#<%= params[:key].gsub(".","_") %>').html('<%= params[:value] %>');
$('#modal-window').modal('hide');
```

in `translations\create.js.erb`
and

```
$('#<%= params[:i18n_backend_active_record_translation][:key].gsub(".","_") %>').html('<%= params[:i18n_backend_active_record_translation][:value] %>');
$('#modal-window').modal('hide');
```

in `translations\update.js.erb`
my add form is form_with and edit is form_for

my `translations_controler.erb` contains:

```
class TranslationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    @translation = Translation.find_by(:locale => find_locale,
                                        :key => params[:key])
    @key = params[:key]
    if @translation.nil?
      @Translation = Translation.new
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout => false }
      format.html
    end
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @translation = Translation.create(translation_create_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @translation.save
        I18n.backend.reload!
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors.full_messages, 
                            status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      @translation = Translation.find(t_id)
      if @translation.update(translation_update_params)
        I18n.backend.reload!
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { } 
      else
        format.json { render json: @translation.errors.full_messages,
                                   status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def t_id
      params[:i18n_backend_active_record_translation][:id]
    end

    def find_locale
      params[:locale].nil? ? I18n.default_locale : params[:locale]
    end

    def translation_update_params
      params.require(:i18n_backend_active_record_translation).permit(:locale,
      :key, :value)
    end

    def translation_create_params
      params.permit(:locale, :key, :value)
    end
end
```

now the modal is working :) :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ton of confusion here.

### The assets pipeline

Javascript placed in the assets pipeline (Webpacker) is compiled at deploy time in production. In Rails 6 you put your "packs" - which are asset manifests in `app/javascripts/packs`. This means the main file(s) which you link to from your layout and which requires the libraries you are using and also your code. You're encouraged to place your own application code in `app/javascripts`.

Webpacker does not pass a `.js` file through the ERB interpreter, so its completely unrealistic to expect that `$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render partial: 'translations/edit_single_translation') %>")` will output anything other then the string `"<%= j (render partial: 'translations/edit_single_translation') %>"`.

Unlike sprockets with webpacker you actually have to [manually install `.js.erb` integration](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/integrations.md#erb). But remember that the file is still compiled at deploy time and not at runtime so the context will be totally wrong and you will not have access to the helpers and view context that would let you render a partial.

### Rails UJS and `js.erb`

When you use `data-remote` on links and forms Rails UJS will send an ajax request for with a `application/javascript` content type. You controller then should respond to `js` and render a js.erb view which is then eval-ed by creating a script element on the page containing the response so the view alters the existing page.

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |f|
      format.js 
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

```
// app/views/things/show.js.erb
el = document.getElementById("#thing");
el.innerHTML = "<%= j @thing.name %>";
```

#### YAGNI

If you just want to render a partial in a modal you don't really need to output the template into JS in the first place. You can just use [`content_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) to create a placeholder in your layout that your views can fill:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenter" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
          <%= content_for :modal_title %>Modal Title<% end %>
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= content_for :modal %><% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Later in the view you can fill in the content:

```
<% content_for :modal_title, "Edit translation", flush: true %>
<% content_for :modal do %>
  <%= render partial: 'translations/edit_single_translation' %>
<% end %>
```

Now all your JavaScript has to do is reveal the modal.

Comment: Ok, that confirms what my alert test implied. So one step further. You explanation is excellent. So if I understand it correct: In show i make a layout with every content element that I have to fill with content params and give them an unique id. I fill a global variable in the controller with the necessary information. I use this global variable in the show.js.erb to generate javascript code that actualy puts the data in the layout.

Comment: No not really. `js.erb` templates are really just a lazy way to do ajax and its one approach you can take. The don't really "put the data in the layout" its a script that when you run it can alter the DOM. This is usually used to output a partial as a HTML string in rails and then inject it into a document (the page in the browser).

Comment: `content_for` on the other hand is all server side. It creates placeholder blocks in the buffer that you can fill with content as the views are being rendered. And you don't need to use global variables in any case - you can pass variables from the controller to the view through instance variables or locals.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments. So in more detail what I want to accomplish: fi: on the registration form I place a translate button after every label. When clicked the modal is activated with the information of that specific label of the default language and the current language and the possibility to change (or add when the translation does not exists) the information of the current language. (buttons appear only when app is in translation mode and the user belongs to the translate policy group of the current language.)

Comment: I found out that in the method `format.js` has to be replaced by `format.js { render :layout => false }` otherwise the <method>.js.erb will not load.